# Is It Possible to Register or Publish Asset Files css,js from Bundle in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

How to register js,css file to head tag from inside bundle automatically? so we don't need to add it manually to layout.

In zend framework there is `HeadScript` and `InlineScript Helper`, `prepend` or `append` method to do this. How about symfony2 ? is it possible too?

In zend framework we can register it like this from module bootstrap :

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$headLink = $sm->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('headLink');
$headLink->appendStylesheet('/assets/MyModule/css/mystylesheet.css');
}
```

I mean, I want register it from e.g `AcmeBlogBundle.php` **so we don't need to add manually** to `<head></head>` in layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files) out, this shows you how to include every js-file inside a directory, without listing them all manually.

Comment: I mean, I want register it from e.g `AcmeBlogBundle.php` to `<head></head>` without editing layout file.

Comment: Well, you could use variables which you assign in your php-file and use in your template, but it's impossible if you want to do this without modifying ANYTHING in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like in Zend. But you can define the appropriate block with js in base layout only once. And then from any template you can put anything you want into this block. Symfony implements a bit different logic than Zend does.

In your layout:

```
<head>
    {% block custom_head_js %}
    <some basic js files for all the pages>
    {% endblock%}
</head>
```

In your templeate:

```
{% block custom_head_js
    '@YourBundleNamespace/YourBundleName/Resources/public/js/your_js_filename.js'
%}

<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

So, as I said it's not necessary to change base layout every time you want to add js into 'head' js files - you have to do it only once.